# Keep referencing array over multiple classes in Java

Tags: java

say I have two classes: players.java and schedules.java

I have an ArrayList (dynamic size) defined in players.c that I want to pass through a function in schedules.c that adds an element into this ArrayList. How can I do this without creating a new array every function call such as?:

```
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
nums = schedules.addNums(nums);
```

The problem is that in my program I have to loop through functions like addNums multiple times which seems wasteful.

I have read that I can declare:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

so that in file schedules.c, I can modify players.nums, but I have read on other stackoverflow posts that use static variables is bad practice. Really what I am looking for is some kind of functionality akin to passing a pointer through a function in c and modifying that ArrayList.

Editted with some code:

In Players.java

```
public class Players {
    public static void main {
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        nums.add(1); // add an element to nums
        System.out.println(''+nums.size()); // should be 1
        nums = schedules.addNums(nums);
        System.out.println(''+nums.size()); // should be 2
        nums = schedules.addNums(nums);
        System.out.println(''+nums.size()); // should be 3
    }
}
```

In Schedules.java

```
public class Schedules {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> addNums(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
        nums.add(2);
        return nums;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is that `c` you are talking about? use a `private ArrayList<Integer> nums= new ArrayList<Integer>();` and getter to access the list

Comment: you can just pass the reference of the arrayList of class players and use the same in schedules class.

Comment: `players.c and schedules.c` in Java?

Comment: Even in C those are not class names but file names ;)

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] with what you have right now (including the static variable).

Comment: By .c I meant .java sorry for the mistake. My question is that if I pass in an arrayList from players.java to schedules.java, do I need to return a new arrayList from schedules.java in order to use it in players.java?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the task correctly but here is example which will not create new instances of `ArrayList`. It is using passing by reference.

```
class Players {
    private List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Integer> getNums() {
        return nums;
    }
}

class Schedules {
    public void addNums(List<Integer> l) {
        // add nums
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        l.add(4);
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this::

```
    Players players = new Players();
    Schedules schedules = new Schedules();

    schedules.addNums(players.getNums());   // after this: players.nums=[1, 2, 4]

    schedules.addNums(players.getNums());   // after this: players.nums=[1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, but I am having difficulty understanding. What is the purpose of getNums?

Comment: @KeithTran `getNums` is so called getter method which provide an access to a field in the class (in this case `Players.nums`). You can just make field `public` and use it like `players.nums` instead of `players.getNums()`. But using methods for accessing class fields is considered a best practice.

Comment: @KeithTran "What is the purpose of getNums?". It gives you a place to slap a breakpoint, and allows for a bit of extended functionality, i.e. you could return a clone of the list or assert something about state ( you can even modify the state of the list but that's a bit horrible and `getNums` would lose its meaning ).

Comment: Oh well, I don't think I will need breakpoints. I do need to modify the list because I am using it as sort of a roster. In other classes I will need to check if size > x, then do y. and this depends on referring to this dynamic array constantly.

Comment: Follow up question. If Players and Schedules are in different files linked together by importing, do I have to change addNums in Public class Schedules to static so that I can class it in Public class Players?

Comment: @KeithTran If you will operate with Schedules instance then no (example:     'schedules.addNums(players.getNums());` If you don't need Schedules instance and just want to call 'addNums' as stateless function you can make it 'static'.